# Istio Egress Gateway Configuration

Tags: curl, istio, istio-gateway

I'm struggling getting my Egress Gateway, Destination Rules and Virtual Service configured correctly.

I'm trying to connect to an external service that's not part of my cluster. Let's call it `example.net` and it's listening on Port `8443`. I've got to use mTLS to connect to this service.

I've followed the [Istio Documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway-tls-origination/) on setting up an Egress Gateway with mTLS origination. I got the expected result.

I'll post my custom configuration files below:

`istio-egressgateway.yaml`

```
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: example-egress-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - example.net
    tls:
      mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: egressgateway-for-example
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
    portLevelSettings:
    - port:
        number: 443
      tls:
        mode: ISTIO_MUTUAL
        sni: example.net

---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: originate-mtls-for-example
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  host: example.net
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: ROUND_ROBIN
    portLevelSettings:
    - port:
        number: 443
      tls:
        mode: MUTUAL
        credentialName: tls-secret
        sni: example.net
```

`istio-egress-virtualservice.yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: direct-example-traffic-through-egress-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
  - example.net
  gateways:
  - example-egress-gateway
  - mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
      port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
        host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 443
      weight: 100
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - example-egress-gateway
      port: 443
    route:
    - destination:
        host: example.net
        port:
          number: 8443
      weight: 100
```

`Service Entry`

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: external-svc-example
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
    - example.net
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
    - number: 443
      name: tls
      protocol: TLS
    - number: 8443
      name: tls-8443
      protocol: TLS
  resolution: NONE
```

When I execute a curl command on one of the pods in the service mesh:

```
curl -v --location 'https://example.net:8443/'
```

Output:

```
* Host example.net:8443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 10.241.0.50
*   Trying 10.241.0.50:8443...
* Connected to example.net (10.241.0.50) port 8443
* ALPN: curl offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
*  CAfile: /cacert.pem
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
* SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
* Closing connection
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

It seems that the pods aren't using the `tls-secret` that is specified when trying to connect to the external service.

I'm not getting anything in my `egress-gateway pod` logs so suspecting routing to the gateway is incorrect?